# WebRTC how i can bypass write_settings permission on android 6.0.1

Tags: webrtc, android-permissions, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

In my android application, I use WebRTC. However, on version 6.0.1, the application crashes due to the lack of write_settings permission. None of the manuals say it's necessary, but without it, the application does not work. I have to request this permission through the content, which consequently causes quite a lot of questions from users. Tell me how to use WebRTC without this permission or as an implicit grant write_settings permission. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please improve your question quality

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hcw3gg

If I try to answer a call or call without the provided permission write_settings then I get this error. Accordingly, to get this permission, I must redirect the user through the content from the corresponding action.